# How to change selection color in appearance?

Tags: macos, themes

I usually use the "graphit" appearance in Yosemite. With "blue" I don't like the selection color. However I miss the red-yellow-green colors on the left from the "blue" appearance.

Is there some (cli) tool where you can customize the appearance and mix both themes up as you desire?

Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selection color as in the highlight text color or the selection box color?

[image]

If it's the appearance, you cannot help it, unless you're willing to pay some money to change it; (*Flavours $19.90*) Flavours looks really good and you can get the trial for free to give it a go.

If it is the Highlight color you are talking about, *completely* customizeable in colors!

Comment: Yes I was looking for that. Hmm doesn't flavors in the end just rewrite some `.xml.plist`?

Comment: I'm not sure... But upon further looking into alternatives to Flavours I found UNO, but it was discontinued, however it still works with Mac OSX 10.4, if it might help.